# Synchronize files with webRequest.GetResponseAsync() hangs

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I synchronize the files from a web application to the client. During batch processing, the application is regularly totally suspended at the line

```
WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

The application can then only be closed by force. Interestingly, all processing runs smoothly when Fiddler is running. How can I fix this behavior?

```
  private async Task<bool> GetFileAsyncRequest(string url, string synchropath)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        string docno = string.Empty;
        var returnValue = false;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)";
            webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Credentials = null;
            webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(CookieContainer.GetCookies(new System.Uri(url)));

            WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            if (webResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] != null)
            {
                filename = webResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", String.Empty).Replace("\"", String.Empty);
                filename = Helper.AdjustPath(filename);
                docno = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1);
                var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff");
                fileSynchronised.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, filename + "  " + timestamp + Environment.NewLine);
                fileSynchronised.SelectionStart = fileSynchronised.Text.Length;
                fileSynchronised.ScrollToCaret();
                returnValue = Helper.ReadStreamFromResponseAndSave(webResponse, synchropath + @"\" + docno + "_" + filename);
            }
            else
            {
                fileSynchronised.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "Error on Download: " + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1) + Environment.NewLine);
                fileSynchronised.SelectionStart = fileSynchronised.Text.Length;
                fileSynchronised.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
        catch(WebException wex)
        {
            if (wex.Response != null)
            {
                using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            returnValue = false;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: How is this being called?

Comment: That's how it's called: bool v = await GetFileAsyncRequest(url, synchropath);

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a thread-lock. To quickly see if maybe this is the case, change await webRequest.GetResponseAsync() to  await `webRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`. You might then hit threading issues but at least you'll be one step closer